# How to deal with the Save As dialog box using Selenium in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download a file using the Selenium Chrome web driver but I don't know how to deal with save as dialog box.

I have seen many answers on how to do this using Firefox but none using Chrome.

Comment: Not sure why this got marked as a duplicate, chrome is clearly not firefox.

Comment: I agree with you, it does seem to differ from the dupe target. I'd actually like to know the answer to this too because I'm trying to do the same thing in C#.

Answer (score 5):

> profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
>   profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom
>   location
>   profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting',
>   False) profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
>   profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
>   'text/csv')

After setting these preferences the browser won't show up pop dialog asking for whether you want to download save or other.
When can then just use `find_some_eleme = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''<somexpath>''').click()` we can use any other method of locating the element xpath/id/css/name... and we use the method click() freely because there won't be a dialog.
or `.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/octet-stream,text/csv")`

For Chrome:

```
chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver"

os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = Options()

# this is the preference we're passing
prefs = {'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```